# Understanding morphism extensions theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

In Galois Theory class, we have seen the following result.

> Let $K$ be a field and $F_1$, $F_2$ be two extension fields of $K$. Let $\alpha\in F_1$ be an algebraic element. Let $\beta \in F_2$. Then, the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\exists f\colon K(\alpha)\to F_2$ s.t. $f|_K = \operatorname{id}$ and $f(\alpha)=\beta$;
> 2. $\beta$ is a root of $\operatorname{Irr}(\alpha,K)$ where $\operatorname{Irr}(\alpha,K)$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ in $K$.

I am trying to understand this statement. If I chose $K=\mathbb{Q}$ with $F_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $F_2=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and I define $$f\colon \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}): \sqrt{2} \mapsto \sqrt{3},$$
then $\sqrt{3}$ should be a root of $x^2-2$ which is not.

- Am I wrong because my $f$ is not a morphism? In this case, how can I know that my $f$ fails to be a morphism?
- If the above point is not the case, what am I considering wrong?

Comment: It simply means there exists a $K$-morphism from $K(\alpha)$ to $F_2$ mapping $\alpha$ to $\beta$ if and only if $\beta$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) $ are of the form  $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$ and elements of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)$ are  $a+b\sqrt2$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q $. If you only demand  $f (\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 3$, then $f(a+b\sqrt2)=a+c\sqrt 2+b\sqrt 3+d\sqrt 6$, where  $c $ and $d $ are arbitrary rational numbers. Hence, your $f $ is not well defined.